# TreeList from Model and Store in Ext Js 6

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have big model in my EXTJs 6 project and I fill him by json data, for example:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "name1",
      "type": "STRING",
      "table": "table1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "name2",
      "type": "STRING",
      "table": "table2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I spend much time for find solution to how build and set my treelist and viewmodel to bind data from store and show it on treelist in this way:

```
table1
   name1
   STRING
table2
   name2
   table2
```

Can anyone explain with examples how do this? In the documentation is not enough information about bind data from store to tree. Thanks.

Comment: You can bind a store to the treepanel like you bind a store to a grid. The documentation is showing how to do it: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.tree.Panel.html

Comment: I'm not sure, because when I set param store = myExampleTreeStore in my treepanel, then I have an error that store is null, but when I do bind = '{myExampleTreeStore'} then not work. I have examples, when I set data inside viewModel, but I don't do this in this way, but by using json file

Answer (score 1):

You will have to change your data format. A tree panel takes a tree store, does not work with a normal store, and a tree store takes data differently from the normal store (more like a tree).

As per the docs of TreePanel, Summary, first line:

> A TreePanel must be bound to a Ext.data.TreeStore.

I found an old fiddle of mine that shows how easily the binding is then accomplished: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/145b

Comment: Okay, but i cannot change my data format. I must use existing data format :( I tried your fiddle, and it's right, but I'm not sure that it's that what I need, because in future, I will use twice trees and I will sending data between this two trees, I know that ext contain plugin to drag data between two trees, but I can't implemented it inside my form. So, maybe do you have any idea how make tree with this data?
{  "columns": [  { "id": 1,"name": "Column1" // child,
      "table": "Aaa" // parent},{
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Column2", // child
      "table": "Aaa" // parent } ]

Comment: It looks like you could use a normal grid with grouping feature.

Comment: I know this is old but trees CAN take flat json data. I'm not sure tree lists do tho.